# Website with Facebook Login: Where to upload screenshot?

Tags: facebook, upload, screenshot

I created a website with the possibility to log in by Facebook.
Everything works fine. It is already used by some people.

Now I want my App to be listed in the App Center. I just read all the recommodations for the App Center before submitting my App detail page to be reviewed.

The guide says clearly:
"Websites with Facebook Login must include at least one screenshot indicating a personalized user experience."

But I can not find a possibility to upload a screenshots at all when I classify my App as "Website with Facebook Login".
I can only find an upload screenshots possibility on the bottom of the "App Details" section when I configure my App to be an "App on Facebook" or an "Mobile Web".

When I look at the "App Detail Preview Page" there are the Facebook Screenshot dummies displayed in the screenshot area.

Can anybody tell me how to change this?

Comment: There should be a section at the bottom of the App Details page that lets you upload Screenshots. Just tried it on a new app configured as a website with FB login, and it shows fine for me. If that's not working for you, can you let me know what is your app-id ?

Comment: I found out why it did not show up in my other App. The screenshots section seem to depend on the App Category selected on the "App Details" page. When I select "Games" and "Adventure" no screenshot section will show up.
When I select "Other" or "App Page" the screenshot section will appear.

Note: When changing the App Category you will have to click on "Save" on the bottom of the page. But the screenshot section will only disappear or apper when you reload the "App Details" page.